# Creating an SSL connection between an Android app and TCP server

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, tcp

I have an Android app which uses a Java TCP client to connect to a Java TCP application server.

In some cases I noticed firewalls or routers that block the port I am using can cause issues so I am trying to use a secure connection.

I have tried using the examples from this link:
[SSLServerSocket](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/0122__SSLServerSocket.htm) but I am always getting a connection timeout.

Server code:

```
  ServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
  serverSocket = sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(port, backlog);
  Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); ---> in a new thread
```

Client code:

```
  SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
  clientSocket = socketFactory.createSocket();
  clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), READ_TIMEOUT); ---> timeout on this line
```

I also tried the more complicated examples in the link but all resulted in a timeout.

I really want to understand what's wrong with this very simple example.

If it's not the way to work with SSL (I see no mention of certificates in this code at all, which I think is necessary in SSL) then why is it given as a working example?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The TCP connect itself is failing with timeout. Nothing to do with SSL. SSL initiation happens once the TCP connection is in place. The packets from client is not reachable on the server. Capture tcpdump. You should see that there is no response to the SYN packet going out from client

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I narrowed it down to the fact that the testing server I was working with was running on my home PC, in which my router blocked port 8080. When I tried to open it in the Admin interface, it says 8080 it not allowed. Very strange... But I think it will work on an actual VM server. I will update when I get the chance to test it. Thanks.